# Accessing ng-hide value of one controller to manipulate ng-style of another controller within a global controller

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I am trying to access the boolean value of ng-hide from one controller to change css properties of another controller using a global controller. Here is the link on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dqmtLxnt/

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="first" ng-style="changeColor" ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        {{ accessOne }}
    </div>
    <div class="second" ng-hide="hideSecond" ng-controller="secondCtrl">
        {{ accessTwo }}
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            if ($scope.hideSecond == true) {
                $scope.changeColor = {
                    'color': 'blue'
                };
            }
        }]).controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.accessOne = "One";
        }]).controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.accessTwo = "Two";
            $scope.hideSecond = true;
        }]);
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
});
```

I am able to change both `changeColor` and `hideSecond` from `mainCtrl` but I'm not able to access the value set from `secondCtrl` in the `mainCtrl`. I even tried setting `hideSecond=true` in `ng-hide` and access it on `mainCtrl` but to no avail.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Angular Service for this, storing the value into a service and than retrieving it from the service in another controller.

In your situation the main controller is loaded before the second controller so it would never know when the value is updated. You can use `$watch` for this, calling an update function when the `$scope` is updated.

Here if your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/dqmtLxnt/2/

Service:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('hide', function() {

    // Allows for passing of data between controllers
    var x = false;
    // Sets savedData to what ever is passed in
    function set(data) {
        x = data;
    }
    // Returns saved data
    function get() {
        return x;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
})
```

Using it in Main Controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return hide.get(); },
    function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        $scope.update(value);
    });

$scope.update = function(value) {
  if (value == true) {
    $scope.changeColor = {
      'color': 'blue'
    };
  }
}
```

Using it in Second Controller:

```
$scope.hideSecond = true;
hide.set(true);
```

**Make sure you inject the service into the app and the service into the controllers.**

Comment: Thanks, this works wasn't sure if I did needed a service for that. But your answer clarifies that.

Comment: No problem, happy coding.